# Scala Spark : Creating variable that contains col names for partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to make several columns that will sum over other column partition by several columns. I want to make a variable that contains all the col names for the partition by, in that way my code will be cleaner. It goes like this

```
var myunit = $"reporttype_code", $"review_code", $"businessgroup_code",
           $"company_code", $"grade_code", $"terminationtype_code"

var semesterly = Window.partitionBy(myunit, $semester)
              .orderBy($year, $month)
              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
var quarterly = Window.partitionBy(myunit, $quarter)
              .orderBy($year, $month)
              .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)

test =  test.withColumn("turnover_over_semester", sum($"val1").over(semesterly))
            .withColumn("turnover_over_quarter", sum($"val1").over(quarterly))
```

I'm gonna make a lot of columns which includes parition by var unit. But the var raised `error : expected ; but , found` Is it possible to create the var other way?

Comment: Did you have a look at the type of the arguments of the `Window.partitionBy` first? (BTW `unit` is a pretty badly chosen name knowing that `Unit` is a Scala type).

Comment: I did, I'm new to scala and I thought I could store the argument to a var since I saw someone did this once `val joinCondition = $"exploded.allcode" === $"original.allcode" && $"exploded.rangeMonth" === $"original.month_date_temp"` so I thought it is possible to do what I want

Comment: joinCondition is an boolean `Expression`. If you had had a look at the `Window` documentation, you would have seen that `partitionBy` function expects a mandatory column as first argument and then either a `Seq` or vararg for more columns.